# How safe is Parse for saving users information?

Tags: parse-platform

Logging in with Facebook through Parse has become a common approach in many apps and using this approach, some of the user's information such username, first_name,last_name,email address is saved in Parse servers. I am wondering how safe is this approach for users?
 if an app starts to make a name and some hackers decide to break into it, then, could they get their hands on all the user's information that is saved in Parse server?
 Is this safety factors something that individual app makers should consider when making apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would consider parse to be fairly safe.

With regards to users, these are by default public readable. If you do not wish outsiders to be able to query information about other users, you might want to change the ACL so that only the owner (the user itself) can read the information.

Should it happen that a hacker got inside the parse.com servers, he will have access to everything. In case you REALLY want to secure your information, I believe you would have to do some encryption on the entries yourself. This though ruins the possibility of queries like e.g. 'give me all users with first name Michael'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the through answer cYrixmorten. One more question could be: if in the worst case a hacker makes it to penetrate into Parse servers and reveal people's information on the net publicly. Then, legally, is it going to be Parse who will be responsible for the consequences or the individual developer? in the case of a sue for example, public would decide to sue Parse or the app maker? just wondering...

Comment: Actually, the standard information, e.g. username, name, email, I do not think is considered critical personal information. It would surprise me if the consequences extend to legal accordance regarding user information. The matter would be different if it contained social security numbers or similar, but in the current state that would be you, as a developer, who had chosen to store such sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks again for the insight. That actually was really helpful to me.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)